# Issue with free() when reading multiple text files (or executed twice?)

Tags: c, arrays, command-line, free

I'm having trouble with a certain part of my code when it comes to reading in multiple files. Here's the bulk of it:

```
    char *a;
    int ch;
    char *line = NULL;
    char *prev_line[999];
    size_t len = 0;
    size_t read;
    if (argc > 1)
    {
      int i = 1;
      FILE *fp;
      while (i < argc)
      {
          a = malloc (MAX_NAME_SZ * sizeof (char));
          fp = fopen (argv[i], "r");
          if (fp == NULL)
          {
              /*Error statement in case an file doesn't exist */
          }
          else
          {
              while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
                  if (strncmp(line, prev_line, read) != 0) {
                      strncat(a, line, read);
                      strncpy(prev_line, line, read);          
                  }
              }
              free(line); 

              fclose (fp);
              changeCase (a);
              printf ("\n");

          }
          i++;            
      }  
   }
   else
   {
       a = malloc (MAX_NAME_SZ * sizeof (char));
       fgets (a, MAX_NAME_SZ, stdin);
       changeCase (a);
       printf ("\n");
    }
}
```

but my issue consists of this portion.

```
while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
    if (strncmp(line, prev_line, read) != 0) {
        strncat(a, line, read);
        strncpy(prev_line, line, read);          
    }
}
free(line);
```

This part of the code only reads in lines that are unique to the previous line. However, when I have multiple arguments and this code is gone through twice, I get a double free or corruption error, which I assume to be because free(line) is done twice.

Is there somewhere else in the code I should move this, or something I could replace it with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [`getline()` documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getline):

> If *lineptr is NULL, then getline() will allocate a buffer for storing the line, which should be freed by the user program.

In your case `line` will only be null for the first file. The call to `getline()` sets `line` to point to something which is then freed.

The next time around the value of `line` is no longer null but instead points to a freed location which should not be written to, and then free is called again on the same value that was previously freed.

Setting `line` back to `NULL` after it is freed should solve your issue.

```
free(line);
line = NULL;
```

This should cause `getline()` to allocate new memory for each file being read.

Comment: I tried this, yet it adds something strange to the beginning of the text from the next file. Like weird symbols. Do I have to reset len and read as well? Edit: The text at the beggining changes each time I run it. Once it was ���%� and next it was �       i�w

Comment: When `line` is `NULL` the `len` value is ignored and `read` is not passed as an input to `getline` so it should have no effect.

Comment: You might try moving `char* line = NULL` to just above the while loop but inside the else statment

Comment: char* line or char *line? I tried both and had the same issue: weird symbols at the start of the next file's text. I assume I was to remove the line = NULL following the free(line) in that scenario

Comment: `char* line` and `char *line` are equivalent in this context. In your example there is not closing bracket for the `if (fp == NULL)` block. I assume that is not the case in your actual code?

Comment: Correct. Just accidentally removed it when copying my code over to post here.

Also: [here's a visual of what the weird symbols I'm talking about are.](https://imgur.com/a/qe5GQrX) , where "hi" is the start of the second text file.

Comment: I finally got it figured out. Thank you for your help tonight! Means a lot :)

Comment: What was the issue?

Comment: Initially, I was getting some string in a, modifying/printing it, then filling a with the new string from the next file. Instead, I moved my modifying/printing function, `changeCase()`, to after the huge if statement. Then I just had to move my `a = malloc (MAX_NAME_SZ * sizeof (char));` to just above the beginning of the big while statement. I then just had to append a newline char to the end of the string after it's finished being read in from the file. Couldn't tell you why it works but it does...